# Como selecionar 2 objetos de um array

Tags: mongodb

Como posso selecionar apenas 2 itens de um `array` de dentro da minha collection?

exemplo:

```
{
    "name": "xpto",
    "age": 11,
    "lista": [{"s": 1}, {"s": 2}, {"s": 3}]
}
```

Preciso pegar os itens que possuam `s` com 2 e 3 onde o `name` seja `xpto` e `age` 11.

Tentei com  `$and` e `$lista.$` mas recebo um erro de `BadValue`:

```
{
    "$and": [
        {"name": "xpto", "age": 11, "lista.s": 2},
        {"name": "xpto", "age": 11, "lista.s": 3}
    ]
},
{
    "lista.$": 2
}
```

O que pode acontecer é de `2` ou `3` não exista, então retornaria apenas uma "lista", como posso selecionar os 2 de dentro do array ou retornar apenas 1 caso os 2 não existam?

O resultado esperado é:

```
{
    "name": "xpto",
    "age": 11,
    "lista": [{"s": 2}, {"s": 3}]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para remover os objetos que não tem `s:2` ou `s:3`, você pode dar um update:

```
db.mycollection.update({

    }, {
        $pull: {
            "lista": {
                s: {
                    $nin: [2, 3]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    false,
    true
);
```

Depois do update seu documento vai ser:

```
{
    "name": "xpto",
    "age": 11,
    "lista": [{"s": 2}, {"s": 3}]
}
```

***Importante***

Note que não coloquei nenhuma condição na query. Esse script altera todos os documentos. Se você quiser, pode filtrar pelo `name` ou `age` no primeiro parametro do `db.collection.update`.

[Referencia na documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#definition)

[$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Comment: A duvida é `como selecionar apenas 2 itens de um array`, deste modo que você apresentou todos os itens do array serão retornados

Comment: adicionei o resultado esperado na pergunta para ficar mais claro

Comment: @RFL entendi! Nesse caso, você pode editar esse objeto depois de executar a query. Você quer remover do array os objetos que ```s``` seja diferente de 2 ou 3?

Comment: não queria adicionar complexidade ao código já que o `mongo` consegue retornar os valores corretos :)
Você alterou sua resposta e ela agora esta fora do escopo, eu perguntei como buscar os itens e não como atualizar minha collection

Comment: @RFL na resposta anterior eu te disse como buscar os itens. O que você quer fazer é manipular o array ```lista```. O que você quer dizer, exatamente, com buscar os itens?